# Spark SQL - IN clause

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I would like to add where condition for a column with Multiple values in DataFrame.

Its working for single value, for example.

```
df.where($"type".==="type1" && $"status"==="completed").
```

How can i add multiple values for the same column like below.

```
df.where($"type" IN ("type1","type2") && $"status" IN ("completed","inprogress")
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the method you are looking for is `isin`:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.where($"type".isin("type1","type2") and $"status".isin("completed","inprogress"))
```

Typically, you want to do something like this

```
val types = Seq("type1","type2")
val statuses = Seq("completed","inprogress")

df.where($"type".isin(types:_*) and $"status".isin(statuses:_*))
```

Comment: How can i build the multiple values dynamically? i tried StringBuilder to build its not working, may be its coming as single string, if i give the values separated by `,` its working.

Comment: What's the reason you're using `Seq`, instead of `Array` or `List`? Thanks!

Comment: @akmal `Seq` is more generic than `List`. `Array` is not part of the scala collections API, so I don't use it unless I have a good reason to do so.

Comment: What is the IN is has a dataframe column to check for values ? how to handle that ?