# select data from Hive where column value in list

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark-sql

I would like to get data from Hive such that: if one column value is in List, then select data from Hive.

Example Data in Hive table is as:

```
Col1   | Col2 | Col3
-------+---------------
Joe    | 32   | Place-1
Nancy  | 28   | Place-2
Shalyn | 35   | Place-1
Andy   | 20   | Place-3
```

I am querying Hive table as:

```
val name = List("Sherley","Joe","Shalyan","Dan")
var dataFromHive = sqlCon.sql("select Col1,Col2,Col3 from default.NameInfo where Col1 in (${name})")
```

I know that my query is wrong, as its throwing error. But I am not able to get proper replacement for `where Col1 in (${name})`.

Comment: what about using DataFrame API ? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218473/spark-sql-in-clause/40218776#40218776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better idea is converting `name` to DataFrame and joins with `dataFromHive`. The inner join does the same as filtering only intersected data.

```
val nameDf = List("Sherley","Joe","Shalyan","Dan").toDF("Col1")
var dataFromHive = sqlCon.table("default.NameInfo").join(nameDf, "Col1").select("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
```

Try to use the DataFrame API. It will make the code easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

convert your List to String (with proper format to use in hive query)

```
val name = List("Sherley","Joe","Shalyan","Dan")
val name_string = name.mkString("('","','", "')")
//name_string: String = ('Sherley','Joe','Shalyan','Dan')

var dataFromHive = sqlCon.sql("select Col1,Col2,Col3 from default.NameInfo where Col1 in " + name_string )
```