# Filter source on Join using Spark to Couchbase datasets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, couchbase

I have an RDD which I join with a Couchbase table using datasets.

```
val couchbaseDS = session.read.couchbase(...)
val myDS = myRDD.toDS()
couchbaseDS.join(myDS, couchbaseDS("key") === myDS("key"))
```

The problem here is that if myRDD comes with only one data, the whole couchbase table is loaded.

Is it possible for spark/connecto to optmize itself and filter the couchbase query first?

For now I solved this by collecting all the keys from myRDD, transforming it to a sequence and then using it at an IN clause at the couchbase source creation.
[Spark SQL - IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218473/spark-sql-in-clause)

```
val mySeq = myRDD.map(row=> (row.key,row.key))
                        .reduceByKey((left,right) => right)
                        .map(row => row._1)
                        .collect()
                        .toSeq
val couchbaseDS = session.read.couchbase(...)
                         .where($"key".isin(mySeq:_*))
val myDS = myRDD.toDS()
couchbaseDS.join(myDS, couchbaseDS("key") === myDS("key"))
```