# case when otherwise dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wrote this :

```
val result = df.withColumn("Ind", when($"color" === "Green", 1).otherwise(0))
```

And I want to extend the condition `$"color" === "Green"` to `$"color" in ["GREEN", "RED", "YELLOW"]`

Any idea how to do this please ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use

`$"color".isin("GREEN","RED","YELLOW")`

Code example:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("Ind", 
when($"color".isin("GREEN","RED","YELLOW"), 1).otherwise(0))
df2.show(false)
```

Outputs:

```
+------+---+
| color|Ind|
+------+---+
|   RED|  1|
| GREEN|  1|
|YELLOW|  1|
|  PINK|  0|
+------+---+
```

A quick search revealed a similar question already answered in stack-overflow: [Spark SQL - IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40218776/2613150)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the column against a list with:

```
val result = df.withColumn("Ind",
  when($"color".in("GREEN", "RED", "YELLOW"), 1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: This is deprecated though, you should use `isin` instead even though it's the exact same method.