# Parameterise a Where clause in SPARK SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I parameterise a query containing an IN clause with a variable number of arguments, like this one?

```
SELECT * FROM Tags 
WHERE ID IN ('01',
        '02',
        '03',
        '04',
        '05',
        '15',
        '16',
        '20',
        '21',
        '22',
        '24',
        '25',
        '27',
        '31',
        '34',
        '43',
        '53',
        '57',
        '60',
        '61',
        '68',
        '70',
        '80',
        '85',
        'A8',
        'A9',
        'B1',
        'B2',
        'B3',
        'B4')
```

In SQL (Sql server ) it is to create a Table valued Parameter
how to achieve this in SPark SQL ? OR  Is there any way to make the where condition values as a pyspark function output ?

Comment: one way might be create a temp table with one column and mention all the values in that column. So that it can be refereed as  SELECT * FROM Tags 
WHERE ID IN (select id from temptable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218473/spark-sql-in-clause/40218776

Answer (score 0):

From the manual ([Manual](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html)):

```
>>> df[df.name.isin("Bob", "Mike")].collect()
[Row(age=5, name='Bob')]
>>>df[df.age.isin([1, 2, 3])].collect()
[Row(age=2, name='Alice')]
```

Thus...

```
tags = ['01', '02', ... 'B4']
df[ df.id.isin(tags) ].collect()
```

Comment: Thanks ,but how it been connected to the where clause in the SQL

Comment: @Nat - PySpark handles that for you.  If you're unclear how, you should include in your question what you already have written and ask how to add this snippet to that.